# How to detect onload event of image which was loaded in custom object

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am creating a sample program to display an image on canvas but would like to enclose actual drawing process into a custom object.

The following code won't show the image as `pictFrame.img.onload` can't catch `onload` event of image file. Chrome console says "TypeError: Cannot set property 'onload' of undefined" with the expression although it can correctly evaluate `pictFrame.img.src` or `pictFrame.img.height`.

How should I detect image loading which is being initiated when the object is created?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function pictFrame(context, imgsrc, pos_x, pos_y, size_x, size_y)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.src = imgsrc;
    this.pos_x = pos_x;
    this.pos_y = pos_y;
    this.size_x = size_x;
    this.size_y = size_y;

    this.draw = function() {
        this.context.drawImage(this.img, this.pos_x, this.pos_y, this.size_x, this.size_y);
    };
}

// These variables must live while the page is being displayed.
// Therefore, they can't be defined within window.onload function.

var canvas;
var context;
var pictFrame;

window.onload = function()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    pictFrame = new pictFrame(context, "darwin.jpg", 10, 10, 200, 200);
};

pictFrame.img.onload = function()      // Can't catch onload event
{
    pictFrame.draw();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are calling before pictFrame gets instantiated. You get this in chrome,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onload' of undefined
```

do like below instead,

```
window.onload = function()
{
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    pictFrame = new pictFrame(context, "images/bahu.png", 10, 10, 200, 200);
    console.log("called");
    pictFrame.img.onload = function()      
    {
        console.log(" onload called");
        pictFrame.draw();
    }
};
```

I mean, do `onload` call after `window.onload` has finished instead of calling it before.

Comment: Thank you, JJPA.  It seems my code ran the function attached to img.onload event before pictFrame = new pictFrame(context, "images/bahu.png", 10, 10, 200, 200) is completely finished.  Your code is 100% right.